# Remember the last radio button to display as default with js-cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, js-cookie

I am using js-cookie and I try to remember the default checked radio button.
If a user click on the dollar currency, the website remembers it and I want the dollar input radio button to be the default one on all pages.

My HTML (just the input):

```
<div class="maincar__currency" id="currency-drop-is">
    <label for="euro-radio-is">
        <div class="currency currency__euro">
            <input type="radio" name="currency-is" value="euro" id="euro-radio-is" class="euro_radio_is" checked>
            <span class="default">EUR</span>
        </div>
    </label>
    <label for="dollar-radio-is">
        <div class="currency currency__dollar">
            <input type="radio" name="currency-is" id="dollar-radio-is" class="dollar_radio_is" value="dollar">
            <span>USD</span>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
let radioButtonEuArray = document.querySelectorAll(".euro_radio_is");
let radioButtonUsdArray = document.querySelectorAll(".dollar_radio_is");

radioButtonEuArray.forEach(function (elem) {
        elem.addEventListener("click", currencyEu);
    });
    radioButtonUsdArray.forEach(function (elem) {
        elem.addEventListener("click", currencyUsd);
    });
function currencyEu() {
        //Set cookies
        Cookies.set('euroCookie', 'euro');
        Cookies.get('euroCookie')
        Cookies.remove('dollarCookie');

function currencyUsd() {
        //Set cookies
        Cookies.set('dollarCookie', 'dollar');
        Cookies.get('dollarCookie')
        Cookies.remove('euroCookie');
}
```

I don't know how to set the 'value' to do this, how can I do that ?

Comment: Why is this using _two_ cookies? Use _one_, and store the selected currency as its _value_.

Comment: Cookie set / get / remove one right after the other, does that really make any sense to you?

Comment: I thought Cookies.set just init one cookie that i could get after. The logic was to have one cookie per currency that I get when I click on the correct one. And then I would have removed the other currencies cookies.

Comment: Why would you need to _get_ the value of a cookie, _right after_ you set it? At that point, you still know what radio button the user currently selected … this makes _no_ sense. You say you want to automatically select the right radio button in _other_ pages - so you need to _read_ the cookie, when you get to one of those pages. But currently you are deleting the cookie right again after you just set it - so it will not even be available on any of these other pages you visit afterwards.

Comment: When the user selects one of the radios, store the currency associated with that into a cookie. One cookie, with one name, not multiple. Name it `usersCurrencySelection`, or whatever makes sense to you in that regard. Do nothing else at this point. Now when the user _enters_ a page, check if that cookie is set. If so, make your script set the corresponding radio button, that has the same value as the one you stored in your cookie, as “checked”.